# Not able to Remove spacing between home indicator and expanded SearchView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I am facing weird issue where there is spacing between up indicator and expanded SearchView. I tried setting various attributes but of no help.

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
```

[image]

After doing layout inspection, I could notice that there is a **view** between up indicator and expandable **SearchView**

[image]

Can someone please point me in correct direction? If I am missing something?

Comment: What is that `View`, exactly? That is, what's the class, ID, etc. you get from the layout inspector? Are you sure nothing in your code is adding that? Is your `Toolbar` possibly in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: @MikeM. I am seeing that View in layout inspector. so unfortunately I am not able to see the id. And yes its in CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Comment: Layout inspector should at least tell you the specific class, yeah? Anyhoo, have you tested without the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? Last I checked, that adds a dummy `View` to the `Toolbar` to figure the collapsing title bounds.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah! Any solution on it :)

Comment: Yeah, what? You got the class name? You tested without the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? Something else?